# Setting up a resonator guitar

Tags: guitar

This may be the wrong place for this question, as it is more gear related. Regardless, I am looking at a used resonator guitar (round neck) that the owner set up intentionally for slide so the action is pretty high. It is playable when fretting and strumming like a normal guitar, but pretty miserable due to the high action.

Could I get it set up again so that the action is low? I plan to play it exclusively like a normal guitar, fretting and strumming. I just don't know if setting the same instrument up for different playing styles wears on the body or anything.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably, the guitar was set up originally as an ordinary playable guitar. Assuming nothing was changed surgically, there's no reason why its originality can't be re-instated.

To obtain the higher action required for slide playing, first the saddles, or bridge would have been raised. Lowering it may involve replacement, but often adjustment is enough.

The neck itself may have had more relief than original - again, truss rod re-adjustment should suffice.

Perhaps the nut itself has also been replaced. That will often tap off, to be replaced with a lower one - or file some off the underside.

Heavier gauge strings can be replaced with lighter, making fretting them easier.

Most, if not all of this, is within the scope of a handy person, but if you're not that guy, a trip to a local luthier, or at very least a local music shop, will be the order of the day.